# Can I revert an apt-get install libfolks25

Tags: apt, uninstall

On Ubuntu Precise and just learning how to use apt-get, I ran:

```
sudo apt-get install libfolks25
```

It installed a slew of files, many marked `vivid`. And, of course, installing things I really didn't want to install. Yes, I should have run in simulated mode first. 
It ended with

```
dpkg: error: configuration error: /etc/dpkg/dpkg.cfg.d/multiarch:1: unknown option 'foreign-architecture'
dpkg: error: configuration error: /etc/dpkg/dpkg.cfg.d/multiarch:1: unknown option 'foreign-architecture'
dpkg: error: configuration error: /etc/dpkg/dpkg.cfg.d/multiarch:1: unknown option 'foreign-architecture'
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
```

If I use `apt-cache policy libfolks25`, it still shows version `0.6.8-2`.

Is there a way to 'undo' to previous versions of all the files it says were installed?

Comment: Anything not clear in the answer?

Comment: Vivid? Why Vivid? [Edit] your question and add the output of `find /etc/apt/ -type f -name '*.list' -print0 | xargs -0 grep 'vivid' {}`

Comment: And the output of `lsb_release -a; cat etc/dpkg/dpkg.cfg.d/multiarch`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, what you need is a [Full System restore](https://askubuntu.com/a/581953/344926) *but* to do that, you need a [Full System Back-up](https://askubuntu.com/questions/569679/whats-a-good-back-up-strategy-for-1-desktop-pc)...

So if this is a quite new install:

1. Re-install the system using [14.04 Trusty Tahr LTS (=Long Term Support)](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop)
2. [Start making System Backups](https://askubuntu.com/questions/569679/whats-a-good-back-up-strategy-for-1-desktop-pc)

Comment: As you've never accepted an answer on this site before: If this answer helped you, don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of this text, which means [Yes, this answer is valid](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer)!  **;-)**